# Existe un equivalente a las plantillas de cadenas de texto (string templates) de javascript, en java

Tags: javascript, java

¿ Existe algún equivalente a las plantillas de cadena de texto de javascript en java ?

https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/template_strings

Ejemplo:

```
`cadena de texto`
`línea 1 de la cadena de texto
 línea 2 de la cadena de texto`
`cadena de texto ${expresión} texto`
```

Lo más cercano que conozco son los StringBuilder, pero el código final no queda tan simple como en los string template de javascript.

Comment: Hola, bienvenido a [es.so], te invito a leer [ask] y a realizar el [tour]. En cuanto a tu pregunta, pudieras lograr algo similar usando [String.format](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html). Otra opción es usar alguna librería externa. Saludos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

primero que nada bienvenido a la comunidad.

Creo entender lo que quieres realizar y se me ocurren 2 alternativas que puedes implementar:

1. Por un lado tenemos a **MessageFormat** el cual toma un conjunto de objetos, los formatea y luego los inserta en una cadena formateada.

   Ejemplo:

> ```
>          Object[] objects = new Object[] {"Cesar", "!"};
>          String mensaje = MessageFormat.format("Mi nombre es {0} {1}", objects);
>          System.out.println(mensaje);
> ```

2. Por otro lado tenemos al famoso `String.format()`.

   Ejemplo:

> ```
> String nombre = "Franco";
> int edad = 30;
> String output = String.format("%s = %d", nombre, edad);
> ```

Aquí te adjunto un link con varios ejemplos de String.format() y sus especificadores (como "`%s`"): https://dzone.com/articles/java-string-format-examples

Comment: Es justo lo que estaba buscando, gracias

Comment: Genial Cesar! recorda darle tilde y puntito para arriba! saludos y a disfrutar del codigo.